# В вопросах не нужен [code]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, удаление-метки

Предлагаю удалить метку [code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code), т.к. она не несет полезной смысловой нагрузки.

Comment: Достаточно снять её со всех вопросов.

Comment: @alexolut, И смысл её существования в чём будет?

Comment: @Aid метки удаляются через удаление их на вопросах. Когда не будет вопросов метка исчезнет через некоторое время.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убрал метку [code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code) у всех 39 вопросов.

Comment: Да ну? Не заметно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, точно, нужно еще игнорируемые почистить

Comment: @Qwertiy, вот теперь все.