# Нужна ли возможность минусовать комментарии?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, репутация

И возможно ли добавить эту возможность на сайт?

Нередко вижу в комментариях к вопросам фразы вроде `"ну а ты как сам то думаешь?"` или `"если ты задаешься таким вопросом - то для тебя это слишком сложно"`, и прочие не несущие никакой смысловой нагрузки комментарии. Лично я считаю их бесполезными, но при этом они не попадают в разряд таких, которые можно помечать тревогой.

Можно что-то делать в таких случаях?

Comment: Почему их нелья пометить тревогой? "Он больше не нужен" -- как раз подходит для приведённых примеров.

Comment: А если комментарий просто не нравится? Лично мне не нравится и я бы его минуснул, будь такая возможность.

Comment: Так статистика с комментариев в статистике не учитывается, смысл от + или - на них?

Comment: Сильно заминусованные комменты можно:     
1. автоматически убирать под кат...    
2. снижать яркость/контрастность...    3. модерировать...

Comment: @ВарламЕрофеич, 1 и 2 методы, возможно, будут действительно хорошо работать, но 3-й метод вряд ли: у меня до сих пор висит в ожидании рассмотрения флаг `off-topic`, которым я отметил один из вопросов *еще 1-го декабря*. Сомневаюсь, что модераторы располагают достаточным количеством свободного времени для *дополнительной области работы -
 модерации комментариев*.

Comment: Я не вижу проблемы в отсутствии кнопки минус, как по мне - чем меньше кнопок - тем лучше. Хорошие коментарии в среде SO всёравно "всплывают" наверх, а те которые так себе - болтаются внизу доступны под кнопкой "ещё". А с кнопкой минус - начнуться ещё разборки *"а почему мой комментарий заминусовали"*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Если добавить возможность минусовать как сейчас есть плюсовать, то это будет полезно. Сейчас наличие плюса у комментария показывает, что это возможный ответ на вопрос. Наличие плюса у коммента несет смысловую нагрузку. Наличие минуса, может расширить эту нагрузку. Будет понятно стоит читать этот коммент или можно не тратить на него свое время. Но в этом случае они как и плюсы не должны быть связаны с репутацией. Или же привязать плюсы/минусы за комментарии к репутации. Получил 1 плюсик вот тебе скажем +1 к репе. Получил 1 минус, вот тебе -1 от репутации. Хотя бы так. Тогда люди будут думать стоит писать всякий бред в комментариях или нет.

Comment: Я согласен, не нужно как-то изменять репутацию за эти минусы. Просто сделать такую возможность для визуального понимания, что данный комментарий неверный как ответ или просто неуместен

Comment: @whizz169 минусы-плюсы не делают комментарий верным или неверным - минусы и плюсы это просто мнение кого-то из членов сообщества. Для неуместных комментариев есть тревога.

Comment: @insolor по такой логике плюсы и минусы такие же мнения для вопросов и ответов. И для неуместных вопросов и ответов есть тревога. Так что получается надо и для вопросов/ответов снять привязку к репутации или отменить наличие?

Comment: @NikolajSarry, см. мой ответ.

Comment: Порой, "плюсы" помогают увидеть интересный комментарий. Особенно это остро проявляется на EnSO. Иногда в вопросах встречается около двух десятков комментариев, и лично мне сложно с первого взгляда перевести текст и понять о чем идет речь. Но когда взгляд "цепляется" за  комментарии с "+", тогда начинаешь переводить их в первую очередь и постепенно выстраивается вся логика обсуждения. Кроме того, никто не отменял чисто психологический фактор: если есть "+", значит комментарий как минимум в тему вопроса либо весьма и весьма полезен. Но я думаю, что репутацию лучше не связывать с комментариями.

Answer (score 15):

Я думаю было бы неплохо. Хотя репы не прибавляется от голосов за комменты и убавляться за downvote'ы не должно...

#### Update

Вариант предложенный Nikolaj Sarry лучше. Я сам думал, что это было бы хорошо , но не стал предлагать ,чтобы не начали пересчитывать все комменты как в "Мы вознаграждаем авторов вопросов" ;)

Comment: Плохой ответ - нет аргументации, чем именно это "неплохо". Суть ответа: "давайте добавим, просто так, чтобы было".

Comment: За него проголосовали четыре человека, значит он вполне нормальный. @insolor вы последнее время очень любите наехать на мой ответы ;)

Comment: 4 плюса - не показатель. Я "наезжаю" на плохие ответы, личность автора не важна. Не нужно думать, что вы какой-то избранный.

Comment: Понятие "плохой ответ" субъективное т.к те кто проголосовал за думали что это хороший ответ.
ИМХО хороший ответ на мете  — это  такой ответ , который выражает отношение автора к вопросу. И не обязательно я должен делать целое исследование , могу просто высказать свое мнение.

Comment: Для того чтобы просто высказать свое мнение достаточно комментария. Если вопрос касается большого изменения в работе сайта, подразумевается, что ответы будут содержать какую-то аргументацию, а не просто личное мнение.

Comment: Вет это безусловно шикарный ответ по вашим меркам (двойные стандарты ;)) :

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5831/%d0%92-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%85-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-code/5832#5832

Comment: Повторю - обсуждение большого изменения в работе сайта. Удаление меток - небольшое изменение. И да, мой ответ прекрасен)

Comment: А это не важно : <q>Для того чтобы просто высказать свое мнение достаточно комментария. Если вопрос касается большого изменения в работе сайта, подразумевается, что ответы будут содержать какую-то аргументацию, а не просто личное мнение. </q>

Comment: Я не вижу смысла продолжать диалог. По поводу вашего ответа я все сказал.

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что ответ Джона Скита на [такой же вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments) на MSE самый правильный:

> Если комментарий неправильный, ответьте на него другим комментарием.
>   Это даёт гораздо больше информации, чем минус, который
>   может означать что угодно.
>
> Я полностью согласен с идеей «отменить случайный плюс»,
>   но не вижу особого смысла в минусовании комментариев.
>
> С точки зрения ценности комментариев с отрицательным голосом: если
>   комментарий указывает, что ответ является неправильным, положительный
>   голос на этом комментарии указывает на поддержку по
>   указанной причине. Они почти как минусы за ответ, по моему мнению -
>   просто без участия репутации.

Comment: В чем-то согласен с этим ответом. Но мне ближе то, что написал Роберт Картейно в первом комментарии к этому ответу. Наличие плюсов и минусов может стать заменой комментариям "Я согласен ... Я не согласен .... Ты молодец ... Ты дурак" и т.п.

Comment: Но в целом идея - не согласен пиши коммент более правильна, при одном условии - описать с чем не согласен и почему, а не просто создавать шум в комментариях. И в целом понятна позиция платформы: голос "за" комментарий избавляет от шума о поддержке решения в комментариях. а несогласные должны выразить свое несогласие и пояснить его, а не просто нагадить и пробежать мимо. Но за частую эти комменты не поясняют ничего и действительно проще заменить их минусами.

Answer (score -4):

#### Вкратце: голоса к комменатриям не нужны. Ни "за", ни "против".

Теперь аргументация:

- Есть основная функциональность сайта - вопросы и ответы.
- Есть мотивационная составляющая - репутация, голоса за/против вопросов и ответов, значки, достижения.
- Есть функциональность для контроля творческого беспорядка, чтобы он не превратился в хаос - модерирование, тревоги, очереди проверки, возможность правки не своего сообщения.
- Дальше есть дополнительная функциональность - например комментарии, они позволяют уточнить вопрос/ответ.
- Также дополнительная функциональность - чаты, они позволяют обсудить что-то, что не умещается в комментариях.
- К комментариям приделана дополнительная функциональность - голоса. Да, дополнительная к дополнительной. Если убрать голоса за комментарии - по сути ничего не изменится. Никто не будет плакать по ним.

**Вывод:** голоса за/против к комментариям не нужны.

Голоса "за" можно оставить, раз уж они есть, голоса "против" добавлять не нужно.

Дополнительно - если добавить голоса "против", то будет больше нытья, "почему мне поставили минус", которое и так присутствует (особенно если снимать репутацию при минусе к комментарию, как предложил **Nikolaj Sarry**). Это нам не нужно, это лишний раздражающий фактор, лишний шум.

Comment: Не согласен.Идея Nikolaj Sarry будет стимулировать писать нормальные комменты.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, как определить что мой коммент нормальный или не нормальный до того как я напишу его? Минуса к комментам будут мотивировать не писать их вообще. Но нет комментов - нет обсуждения, для которого они нужны.

Comment: Человек априори всегда считает свой коммент нормальным. Даже если на предыдущий коммент прилетела куча минусов, это не удержит его от написания комментария такого же качества, как и предыдущий. В конце концов он просто перестанет писать их и уйдет с сайта.

Comment: Нет минусов будут писать больше комментариев из категории "он больше не нужен" и модераторы будут их обрабатывать вместо того , чтобы тот кому заминусовали подумал и удалил или по крайней мере больше не писал некачественных комментов.Или можно удалять комментарии с -3 голосами .
А за +1 не помешает и +1 репы...

Comment: А с сайта и так многие люди уходят. И вряд ли голосование против комментов увеличить их число. А вот количество спама уменьшит.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, мое мнение: **не нужно** пытаться мотивировать участников меньше комментариев любого качества. Пусть будет свободное обсуждение. Комментариев действительно плохого качества очень мало, тревог достаточно.

Comment: Для "свободного  обсуждения" есть чат. И комментариев плохого качества довольно много.(Много и мало — понятия субъективные)

Comment: Чат есть, и обсуждение в комментариях, зашедшее слишком далеко, легким движением переносится туда. Поэтому - не надо никак пытаться регулировать комментарии (опять же, кроме крайних случаев, для которых есть тревоги).

Comment: Снижать контрастность "заминусованных" ответов - хорошее начало, вот только "пеленать" сами комменты к подобным ответам ни к чему. Предлагаю убрать "пелену" с комментариев...

Comment: "пелена" - снижение яркости либо контрастности написанного...

Answer (score -5):

Я предлогаю эту возможность создать для пользователей с репутацией более  чем `20к`. Почему я так думаю: Кроме того, что комментарии могут быть вредными в плане этикета, а может просто неуместными(короче все, которые можно отмечать тревогой)_ минусы на комментариях будут означать, что они:

1. Содержат неверную    информацию.
2. Они ничем не могут помочь обсуждению.
3. Содержание не имеет  отношение к вопросу/ответу.
4. Другие везкие причины...

Увидев минусованный комментарий, лично я пойму, что стоит подумать о том, нужно ли обращать внимания на такой комментарий. А если он мой, то для меня будет полезно узнать, что я был не прав, потому что, скорее всего, пользователи с большой репутацией, это пользователи с хорошими знаниями. А также, высокая репутация сама по себе говорит, что человек давно не новычок в сайте, а значит он заботится о качестве сайта и не просто так ставит минусы. Поэтому я к этому отнесусь вполне серьезно... P.S. Не то получится, что каждый школьник может ставить минусы(достаточно и того, что они могут  минусовать ответы и вопросы...

Comment: И сколько в процентах активных людей с 20к репы на сайте? Как бы не вышло, что плюсы будет ставить 1 человек.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, 54 человека на 180к участников)

Comment: @insolor tired of this drama, вполне достаточно_ думаю минусовать тоже немного придется

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama, благодарю за статистику)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, как по мне, маловато будет, зачем вообще тогда вводить фичу, которую будут использовать раз в месяц?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, а почему вы допускаете, что  таких участников скоро не станет намного больше?  Зачем вводить фичу?  Идея в том, что если уж вводить, то  сделать нотацию на качество, а не количество. Не важно как это сделается, я лишь образно выразился по поводу количества реп.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, полтора года здесь, как видел одних и тех же людей в топе, так и вижу. В этом нет ничего плохого, но новички либо очень быстро теряют интерес, либо им банально не хватает простых вопросов. Дело не в конкретной цифре в 20к, дело в `пользователи с большой репутацией, это пользователи с хорошими знаниями`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, да, тут я не стал вдоваться в подробности. Конечно это не всегда так, и новычком сайта вполне может оказаться спец высокого класса. Тут, как говорится: мое дело _  предлогать...