Необходимо удалить метку [генер]
По-моему, я случайно создала метку‍️‍ [генер], ее необходимо удалить

Если с этой меткой не будет вопросов она сама удалиться.

@чистов_n, через какое время?

Я искала генерация-кода, что-то такое, при https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1600987/revisions редактировании. Метку добавила, кодогенераторы, а эта часть, что я вбила в поиск-осталась, я после редакции еще просматриваю вопрос/ответ, и вижу метка генер, думаю, аааааа, это что я добавила...а почему тут написано https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1600996/revisions дух создал...я же со своего аккаунта делала все действия вышесказанные, а дух, это если не залогиниться

Ничего не нужно делать. Удалится сама через сутки или несколько суток (точно не знаю, но примерно так). Добавлять описание к такой метке не нужно.

А зачем вам точно? Метки постоянно удаляются, тут даже целый чат редакторов, которые удаляют метки из вопросов. Через какое-то время метки без вопросов пропадают, ничего дополнительно делать не нужно.

@insolor, удалила коммент, тк увидела, вы отредактировали свой точно не знаю, но примерно так) //зачем мне точно? потому что я добавила по ошибке, и хочу ее исправить)))она меня бесит, ускользнула случайно от меня. Я еще вообще меток не создавала, и на тебе...начало (сниф)

@insolor, а это что https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1600996/revisions, почему дух создал пишется?

Можно предположить, что автор метки берется из правок вопроса, где метка была создана (странно, но ладно). Т.к. вопросов нет, то пишет, что создано духом.

@insolor, а есть примеры с удаленными метками? то есть она точно удалится, или там останется "шрамик"?

я ее добавила в "отслеживаемые", она удалится из моего списка тоже?

https://youtube.com/shorts/I7y33CwSm2I?si=ZbYEig2BITad5uE6 когда решила исправить, но что то пошло не по плану, (добавлю в отслеживаемые, чтоб видела её, добавлю описание, вдруг тот, кто прочтёт у него доступ к "удалить", создам вопрос на мете, может кто все таки удалит... ) ...

Удалится полностью. Какой еще "шрамик"? В ослеживаемых скорее всего тоже. Если нет - это будет баг. Не нужно суетится, это ерундовое событие.

Свежий пример это в чатике редакторов можно посмотреть. Из своего - вот пример: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5832/1365

Да, отлично. (шрамик-это след) я например, когда ввожу метку code, как будто её и не было никогда... (хотя может, если много репы, типа видно, что удалённая метка ‍...)

Ну все, уже нет вашей метки. Даже в очереди проверок не отображается, для какой метки правка предлагалась: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/948828

insolor, https://i.sstatic.net/3k5ktMlD.jpg и в списке осталась багом...

@Dev18 удалите ее из этого списка.

Нет, она останется со мной на веки вечные
